# Scaling and locking SpriteRenderer Image to anchor points

Tags: unity, 2d, image, scale

I have a script that uses Index to change an object's sprite using `OnClick` to move through the sprites, like a slideshow. I want the image to scale to the size of my anchor points, because I've noticed that when I stretch the game or put the game on "maximize on play" the image stays the same size and doesn't scale to the size of my anchor points. How would I do that?
This is my script:

```
public Sprite[] Images;
//Index starts at one because we are setting the first sprite in Start() method
public int _Index = 1;

void Start() {
    //Set the image to the first one
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Images[0];
}

public void onClick(){
    //Reset back to 0 so it can loop again if the last sprite has been shown
    if (_Index >= Images.Length)
        _Index = 0;
    
    //Set the image to array at element index, then increment
    this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Images[_Index++];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(code updated to integrate yours directly)  This covers resizing the image, but it doesn't cover the aspect ratio.  The aspect ratio could be easy (`targetHeight = TargetWidth * (height/width)`), or complex if you are trying to use more shaping features/positioning.

```
 public Sprite[] Images;

 //Index starts at one because we are setting the first sprite in Start() method
 public int _Index = 1;

 void Start(){
     //Set the image to the first one
     this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Images[0];
 }
 
 public void onClick(){

     var renderer = GetComponent(SpriteRenderer);
     if (renderer == null) return;

     //Reset back to 0 so it can loop again if the last sprite has been shown
     if (_Index >= Images.Length)
         _Index = 0;

     //Set the image to array at element index, then increment
     renderer.sprite = Images[_Index++];
 
     transform.localScale = Vector3(1,1,1);
 
     var width = renderer.sprite.bounds.size.x;
     var height = renderer.sprite.bounds.size.y;
 
     var targetWidth = 16; // replace this with the code to get the width you want
     var targetHeight = 9; // replace this with the code to get the height you want

     transform.localScale.x = targetWidth / width;
     transform.localScale.y = targetHeight / height;
 }
```

However, You could just use the [UI Image](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-image), which should scale with the screen size by default.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Do I have to make a new script or add this into my script. :)

Comment: I would add it to the end of your onClick method.  And my first line, would be replaced by "var go = this.gameObject;"

Comment: If this is UI I think it would be much better if the whole thing is setup using  UI components and then properly setup RectTransform hierarchy will automatically handle it.